# Azure API Management and DBContext

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-appservice

I am looking into using Azure App Services to host a ASP.Net API project. Everything seems to work except that it seems like the `connectionstring` for the EF8 DBContext does not get initialized. I even tried hard coding the connection string when the `DBContext` is added in Programs.cs. I did find that if I specify the connection string in the API controller constructor, the connection works. It seems like the connection string does not get passed/registered. When debugging everything works fine.

Adding `DBContext` with hard coded `connectionstring` with security items hidden:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PortalDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=hidden_url;Initial Catalog=hidden;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=hidden;Password=hidden;Trust Server Certificate=True")
```

I must be missing something but not sure what the issue is.
In the API controller constructure if I set the connection string everything works.

```
_context.Database.SetConnectionString("connections string");
```

This tells me something is not correctly configured as the connection string is not set at this time. The context is passed, except the `connectionstring`.

I even tried hard coding the connection string when the `DBContext` is added in Programs.cs. I did find that if I specify the connection string in the API controller constructor, the connection works. It seems like the connection string does not get passed/registered. When debugging everything works fine.

Comment: What is the framework version of your WebApp? Can you please share your configuration file.